# How to handle no input using input() function in Python?

Tags: python, input

I tried to write a program which requests user to choose an option, however, Python always show an error message if user choose nothing and only input ENTER. Here is an example

```
tmp=input("Choose program type:1.C++;2.Python;3.PERL (ENTER for default 2.Python)")
print tmp, type(tmp)   #test input
if len(str(tmp)) == 0:
  tmp=0

if tmp == 1:
  print "User choose to create a C++ program.\n"
  DFT_TYPE=".cpp"
elif tmp ==2:
  print "User choose to create a Python program.\n"
  DFT_TYPE=".py"
elif tmp ==3:
  print "User choose to create a PERL scripts.\n"
  DFT_TYPE=".pl"
else:
  print "User choose incorrectly. Default Python program would be     created.\n"  
DFT_TYPE=".py"
```

if I input ENTER only, I got error message like below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./wcpp.py", line 17, in <module>
    tmp=input()   File "<string>", line 0

    ^ SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

How to handle such case if user input nothing? Any further suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Works fine in Python 3 btw. Not sure if it's an earlier version issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using python 2, use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

```
tmp=raw_input("Choose program type:1.C++;2.Python;3.PERL (ENTER for default 2.Python)")
...
...
if tmp!='':
    tmp = int(tmp)
    pass #do your stuff here
else:
    pass #no user input, user pressed enter without any input.
```

The reason you are getting error is because in python2 `input()` tries to run the input statement as a Python expression.

So, when user gives no input, it fails.

Answer (score 1):

you can use raw_input with a default value

```
x = raw_input() or 'default_value'
```